# How to load Json data to drop down

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

here in this code i am trying to get the json value. i am able to get the key value, but i am not able to get the val's value.

How can i do this?

Jquery code:

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
    var items = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        alert(key);
        alert(val);
        items.push('<option value="' + key + '">'+key+'</option>');
        //items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' +key + '</li>');
    });
    $('#project-list').html(items.join(''));
});
```

here is json data

```
{ 
    "trng-java": {"1":"5"}, 
    "trng-jast": {"2":"5"},
    "trng-caml": {"3":"4"},
    "trng-linx": {"1":"5"}
}
```

When i run this, i am getting the key value, but val's value is coming as Object object.

Comment: because it's an object {} - object [] array

Comment: exactly,.. ie, in the first iteration of the loop key would be "trng-java" but val would be "{"1":"5"}" hence Object object.  you'd need to use val[0] or val[1] whether you want "1" or "5" as @Cԃաԃ pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

the value is an array it seems, like others suggested use `val[index]` to get the values but if you want it to be a string use

```
 var valString = val.toString();
```

this will return *1,5*  ,   *2,5* ...

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing: `val[0]`

```
  $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
var items = [];
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
alert(key);
alert(val[0]);
items.push('<option value="' + key + '">'+key+'</option>');
//items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' +key + '</li>');
});
  $('#project-list').html(items.join(''));
});
```